# "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript" Won't Update

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, updates, visual-studio-extensions

Pounding on the update button in this screenshot does nothing. Nothing is downloaded, installed, etc. No message, nothing at all! Clicking "Release Notes" and "More Information" also does nothing.

Searching for this update yields nothing useful, too. What ever shall I do?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is Google Chrome your default browser by chance?  I see the same behavior in that case, but not when IE or Firefox is.  What Wade suggested earlier is [precisely the file](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687) that pressing that button would have downloaded for you.

Comment: Yep - Chrome. I will switch to IE temporary, out of curiosity, to see if that fixes the issue...

Comment: Setting IE as the default browser did fix this issue. Weird and lame! Thanks!

Comment: You may be experiencing an issue reported to Chrome recently - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156400 There's a workaround suggested in the comments for this issue

Comment: fantastic info Jordan - I've passed on internally to some folks working to diagnose/fix... how ironic the report came from Scott Hanselman.

Comment: may be that is a prblm with chrome. I used firefox by the way and it takes me the download file. File size if around 3MB

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue in Visual Studio 2012. Although I don't know how to solve this specific problem, I was able to find and apply the update from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687. Once installed VS no longer lists the update.

Comment: Thank you. See Jim O'Neil's answer for the "fix."