# After installing "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript" update, it still appears as an available update

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

After clicking on update, unlike ["Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript" Won't Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065812/visual-studio-extensions-for-windows-library-for-javascript-wont-update), I can successfully download the update .exe.

My issue is that even after successfully installing the update, it still appears in the "Extensions and Updates" window after the install. No amount of restarting VS or rebooting my machine will resolve this.

The current version that VS claims is installed is: 1.0.9200.20789 and the version it is trying to update to: 1.0.9651.40228

Does anyone know how to force VS to recognise the update? I have tried to repair the installation, also gone in to programs in Control Panel and un-installed it (both versions - I had a previous version that seemed to be linked to VS2012) and re-installed it.

The features of this extension are useful, so I don't particularly want to un-install it, to avoid seeing the update.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this workaround:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/847258/vs2013-keep-saying-windows-library-for-javascript-needs-updating-1-0-9651-40228

1. Get "msiinv" from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx
2. Run `msiinv.exe -p > out.txt`
3. Open "out.txt" and find "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript". There should be two of them, one with version 1.x and second with version 2.1.
4. Lookup the product code for v1.x and uninstall it using `msiexec /x`. For me, the product code was `{D5FEB7A1-5D0F-4CDC-8290-F52DFB53AF23}`, so I ran 
   `msiexec /x {D5FEB7A1-5D0F-4CDC-8290-F52DFB53AF23}`

If you need to reinstall the extension, you can get it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40793

Comment: Just a word of "warning": I somehow had 3 (!!?!?) versions of the extension installed on my machine. Remove all the old one and leave only the new one for this fix to work. Other than that, this solution worked as advertised.

Comment: Thanks Joce, I was in the same situation! Maybe I got a different copy installed every time I tried to update it... as a matter of fact I had to remove 3 out of 4 packages, the older ones, to make it work! What was strange is that step 2 only showed TWO packages on each run, but each uninstall made another old package appear.. I just repeated steps 2-3-4 until I had only one instance, the newer one..

Answer (score 12):

My alternative solution, same as posted on the Microsoft Connect:

> A easier way (at least for me)...
>
> Tested on Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and Windows 8.1.
>
> Open the folder:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\
>
> Probably it will be hidden, just press Windows+R and paste the path and hit Enter.
>
> Press F3 to search in the folder, look for:
>   WinLibJS_CORE.msi
>
> Some results will brought up for you.
>
> Open the properties window and look at the details page of the file.
>   Check the subject field, the version is specified there.
>
> If you are viewing the search results in "details view mode" (Ctrl+Shift+6), you can just > hover the mouse on the installer and check the tooltip, the version will be there too.
>
> Now, just uninstall the old versions and done ;)
>
> At least it worked for me.

Comment: Did this for VS 2013 Pro. I like this because you don't need to download and execute a tool.

Comment: To uninstall, right click the .msi-file and select "Uninstall" in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Another PowerShell alternative on fixing this may also be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2014/04/21/can-t-update-visual-studio-2013-extensions-for-the-windows-library-for-javascript.aspx